# How to filter an excel columns which contain date/time as string

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet to filter a Column. The column relates to total experience of a person. The values are like 5years 2Months, 32Years 6Months etc... all the values are in String format. I need the following functionality.

- 1. when i enter >5 in a textbox(which i will create in a form), it should display only experience which are less than 5(filtering) . I need an idea how to do this in vba.

Can anyone help..? I just need a way to do this.

[image: Screenshot of the column]

Comment: The `>` symbol means `greater than`, not `less than`. If you enter `>5` it will mean `greater than 5`, not `less than 5`. Apart from these basics of understanding the symbols for the operators, you don't specify what unit the `5` should be applied to. Years or months? The data architecture in this sheet is very unfortunate, especially since there is not even a space between the number and the unit text. Who creates such bad data??? And why??

Comment: It would be so much easier to use a whole number for months, like 38 for three years and two months, but at least determine the duration with a consistent unit. Using a text field like this for a value that can be expressed by a number is -- well -- very unwise. You would be much better off changing the way the duration is stored, than trying to find a complicated VBA routine that will splice the text back into a numeric value.

Comment: really sorry for that mistake @teylyn greater than 5 years i meant. Do you have that complicated routine in your hand. like splitting the year then adding it to a list A in integer form, then removing all the values less than 5  nd again filtering the excel with values in list A..? Is this possible in VBA..?

Comment: Less than five WHAT? Years or months??

Comment: Years, I just need to get those years greater than 5

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following screenshot. Column a has the unfortunate text with years and months.

[image]

Column B splits out the years. Column C splits out the months. Column D has the total number of months for the time frame. With this in place, you can filter by any of the columns using the filter options of the Autofilter built into an Excel table.

The formulas are as follows:

Years: `=MID([@total],1,FIND("Years",[@total])-1)+0`

Months: `=MID(SUBSTITUTE([@total],"Months",""),FIND(" ",[@total])+1,99)+0`

Duration in months: `=([@years]*12)+[@months]`

Now just use the filters in the drop down butttons of the column headers and there is no need for VBA at all.